# How to write a better regex in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have two scenarios to match . Length should be exactly 16.
Pattern should contain `A-F,a-f,0-9` and `'-'` in 1st case.

1. `AC-DE-48-23-45-67-AB-CD`
2. `ACDE48234567ABCD`

I have tried with `r'^([0-9A-Fa-f]{16})$|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}\-){7}[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$'`this , which is working fine . Looking for better expression .

Comment: if it is working fine, then what are you actually looking for? What is it that you think is *"better"* in this case?

Comment: You could replace all `0-9` with `\d`.

Comment: If there is an option for your matcher to ignore case, you could get rid of `A-F` or `a-f`.

Comment: In Python you could strip out all `-` characters, then check it matched the second case.

Comment: @blueteeth stripping `-` characters would allow something like `ABCD-E-F01-23-456789` to match which I don't think is OP's intent

Comment: Thanks a lot guys  . Got some idea to work around it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the regex by considering the string to be a group of two hex digits followed by an optional `-`, followed by 6 similar groups (i.e. if the first group had a `-`, the subsequent ones must too), followed by a group of 2 hex digits:

```
^[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}(-?)([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}\1){6}[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}$
```

Use of the `re.I` flag allows you to remove the `a-f` from the character classes:

```
^[0-9A-F]{2}(-?)([0-9A-F]{2}\1){6}[0-9A-F]{2}$
```

You can also simplify slightly further by replacing `0-9` by `\d` in the character classes (although personally I find `0-9` easier to read):

```
^[\dA-F]{2}(-?)([\dA-F]{2}\1){6}[\dA-F]{2}$
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/NdeXYM/2)

Sample python code:

```
import re

strs = ['AC-DE-48-23-45-67-AB-CD',
        'ACDE48234567ABCD',
        'AC-DE48-23-45-67-AB-CD',
        'ACDE48234567ABC',
        'ACDE48234567ABCDE']

for s in strs:
    print(s + (' matched' if re.match(r'^[0-9A-F]{2}(-?)([0-9A-F]{2}\1){6}[0-9A-F]{2}$', s, re.I) else ' didn\'t match'))
```

Output

```
AC-DE-48-23-45-67-AB-CD matched
ACDE48234567ABCD matched
AC-DE48-23-45-67-AB-CD didn't match
ACDE48234567ABC didn't match
ACDE48234567ABCDE didn't match
```